# Calculating $\iint_{D} \left(x-y\right)dxdy$ where $D=\left\{0\le x-y\le 1,\:1\le xy\le 2\right\}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

$$\iint_{D} \left(x-y\right)dxdy$$ where $D=\left\{0\le x-y\le 1,\:1\le xy\le 2\right\}$

So the substitution is pretty obvious, but j is: $J\:=\frac{1}{x+y}$ $$$$
I dont see how I get rid of the denominator and what is the new integral without x,y.

Can somebody show me what is the trick here and how Do i get a new integral with the substitution $u=x+y, v=xy$?

Comment: Does the fact that $(x-y)^2+4 x y = (x+y)^2$ help?

Comment: yes, now the only little question is if I take the root to express what I want, how do I decide if to take a plus or a minus the root? 
From first view it can be both, isn't it ?

Comment: Use a plus sign since you need $|J|$.

Comment: Remember that you multiply by the modulus of the Jacobian, as the scale factor.

Comment: Forgot about the modulus, of course ) Sorry, a'm a little bit rusty. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One little picture says more than a long speech !
And brute force calculus :

[image]

Comment: how did you make the image?

Comment: With softwares "Sine qua non" and "ms-paint".

Comment: what Sine qua non software did you use?

Comment: "Sine qua non" is the name of the software : http://patrice-rabiller.fr/SineQuaNon/menusqn.htm